# How do I disable a Windows dialog box notification from the registry?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, regedit

I have disabled the Task Manager from the registry.  After disabling it, when I press Ctrl+Alt+Del a dialog box appears which tells me that the Task Manager has been disabled by the Administrator.

How can I disable this type of dialog box, warning me that the Task Manager has been disabled?

[image]

Comment: You want to disable the Ctrl-Alt-Del dialog box?  I'm pretty sure that one is protected.

Comment: I want to disable the notification dialog box of window, which notify me that your task manager have been disabled by your administrator.

Comment: Could you edit your question to add a screenshot of the dialog you are trying to hide?

Comment: @heavyd please check this link I have uploaded the image of dialog box which I want to disable. 
http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?7590143d85.png